# why cant we add $scope as parameter for angular services?

Tags: angularjs

i have tried the following code

this my service

```
angular.module('DriverApp').service('driverservice',['$scope',function ($scope) {

 $scope.drivers = [{
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    birthday: '2000-10-01',
    vehicle: 'Nissan-GTR',
    ranking: 1
}, {
    firstName: 'Mike',
    lastName: 'Black',
    birthday: '2002-06-12',
    vehicle: 'Merc SLK 500',
    ranking: 2
}];

returnDriver=function(){
    return $scope.drivers;
}

}]);
```

and this is my controller

```
angular.module('DriverApp').controller('MainController',['$scope','driverservice',function (driverservice,$scope) {

$scope.getDrivers=driverservice.returnDriver();

}]);
```

but this is showing a error has folowsnin the console

[image]

Comment: Services are singletons. There is a single instance of each service. But there are many, many $scope instances. Which one would be injected in the service?

Comment: @JBNizet, That's an excellent explanation as to why you can't use `$scope` in a service.

Comment: `['$scope','driverservice',function (driverservice,$scope)` => `['$scope','driverservice',function ($scope, driverservice)` The order should be matched.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `$scope` in a service or factory. `$scope` is what allows you to bind your controller actions to your view and vice-versa. Controllers are the only thing used to interact with the view in following the traditional MVC pattern.

Your service(s) should only be used to feed data to/from your controllers.

Read the [AngularJS Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) to understand how `$scope` works.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass $scope as parameter from controller as bellow

```
$scope.drivers = 10;
 driverservice.save(drivers).success(function() { 
           alert('saved successfully!!!'); 
       }).error(function(){
           alert('something went wrong!!!');
       });
```

In your driverservice service, define the save function:

```
angular.module('DriverApp').service('driverservice',['$http',function ($http) {
    this.save = function(drivers){
        //Do stuffs
    }
}
```